# Request body as int instead of string

Tags: ansible, jinja2, cisco

I'm trying to pass a registered value (from a csv) into a body. However, whenever attempting to do so it want to return a string - but API expect an int. Even when attmpting to convert it to an int, it still results in string.

```
- name: Creating vlan
    cisco.intersight.intersight_rest_api:
      resource_path: /fabric/Vlans
      update_method: post
      api_body: {
    "AutoAllowOnUplinks": true,
    "EthNetworkPolicy": "{{ ethpolicies.api_response.Moid }}",
    "IsNative": false,
    "MulticastPolicy": "{{ multicastpolicies.api_response.Moid }}",
    "Name": "{{ item.Name }}",
    "VlanId": "{{ item.VLAN | int}}"
  }
    register: vlancreate
    with_items:
      - "{{ vlanlist.list }}"
```

### Expected result

```
"invocation": {
    "module_args": {
        "api_body": {
            "AutoAllowOnUplinks": true,
            "EthNetworkPolicy": "...",
            "IsNative": false,
            "MulticastPolicy": "...",
            "Name": "test2",
            "VlanId": 100 <- int
```

### Actual result

```
"invocation": {
    "module_args": {
        "api_body": {
            "AutoAllowOnUplinks": true,
            "EthNetworkPolicy": "...",
            "IsNative": false,
            "MulticastPolicy": "...",
            "Name": "test2",
            "VlanId": "100" <- string
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the dictionary on the fly thus avoiding the Jinja evaluation to strings. For example, create variable *api_body_default* (below simplified for testing) and combine it with the items from the list. Given the list

```yaml
    vlanlist:
      list:
        - Name: test
          VlanId: 100
```

the task

```yaml
    - name: Creating vlan
      cisco.intersight.intersight_rest_api:
        resource_path: /fabric/Vlans
        update_method: post
        api_key_id: my_api_key_id
        api_private_key: my_api_private_key
        api_body: "{{ api_body_default|combine(item) }}"
      register: vlancreate
      loop: "{{ vlanlist.list }}"
      vars:
        api_body_default: {
          "AutoAllowOnUplinks": true,
          "IsNative": false
        }
```

should work as expected

```yaml
  vlancreate:
    changed: true
    msg: All items completed
    results:
    - ansible_loop_var: item
      api_response: {}
      changed: true
      failed: false
      invocation:
        module_args:
          api_body:
            AutoAllowOnUplinks: true
            IsNative: false
            Name: test
            VlanId: 100
          api_key_id: my_api_key_id
          api_private_key: VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER
          api_uri: https://intersight.com/api/v1
          list_body: []
          query_params: {}
          resource_path: /fabric/Vlans
          return_list: false
          state: present
          update_method: post
          use_proxy: true
          validate_certs: true
      item:
        Name: test
        VlanId: 100
      trace_id: ''
    skipped: false
```